# levels option in pandas concat

Tags: python, pandas

```
df1 = DataFrame(np.arange(6).reshape(3, 2), index=['a', 'b', 'c'],
        columns=['one', 'two'])
df2 = DataFrame(5 + np.arange(4).reshape(2, 2), index=['a', 'c'],
        columns=['three', 'four'])

>>> df1
   one  two
a    0    1
b    2    3
c    4    5

>>> df2
   three  four
a      5     6
c      7     8


res = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1, levels=['level1', 'level2'],
        names=['upper', 'lower'])
>>> res
   one  two  three  four
a    0    1      5     6
b    2    3    NaN   NaN
c    4    5      7     8
```

My question is why levels and names are not shown in res output above? Any real example how levels option is used?

Thanks for your time and help

Answer (score 8):

Really interesting question.

I do research in [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/search?page=1&tab=Relevance&q=%5bpandas%5d%20concat%20keys%20levels) but never is used :(

But in [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html#more-concatenating-with-group-keys) is one sample with notice:

> Yes, this is fairly esoteric, but is actually necessary for implementing things like `GroupBy` where the order of a categorical variable is meaningful.

Also [`docs`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) says:

> **levels** : list of sequences, default None. Specific levels (unique values) to use for constructing a MultiIndex. Otherwise they will be inferred from the keys.

So it add new levels to `MultiIndex`:

```
res = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1,
                keys=['level1','level2'], 
                levels=[['level1', 'level2','level3']], 
                names=['upper', 'lower'])

print (res)
upper level1     level2     
lower    one two  three four
a          0   1    5.0  6.0
b          2   3    NaN  NaN
c          4   5    7.0  8.0

print (res.columns)
MultiIndex(levels=[['level1', 'level2', 'level3'], ['four', 'one', 'three', 'two']],
           labels=[[0, 0, 1, 1], [1, 3, 2, 0]],
           names=['upper', 'lower'])
```

Same without parameter `levels`:

```
res = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1,
                keys=['level1','level2'], 
                names=['upper', 'lower'])

print (res)
upper level1     level2     
lower    one two  three four
a          0   1    5.0  6.0
b          2   3    NaN  NaN
c          4   5    7.0  8.0

print (res.columns)
MultiIndex(levels=[['level1', 'level2'], ['four', 'one', 'three', 'two']],
           labels=[[0, 0, 1, 1], [1, 3, 2, 0]],
           names=['upper', 'lower'])
```

Comment: thanks for help. I am not able to understand how to interpret labels in print(res.columns) output. how these values are produced.

Comment: I try to explain it - levels are all possible unique values of MultiIndex. And labels map this levels - So for first level `['level1', 'level2', 'level3']` is mapped by `[0, 0, 1, 1]` and output is `['level1', 'level1', 'level2', 'level2']`

Comment: to sum up `keys` go to values of `MultiIndex` to mark each `DataFrame` in resulting concatenation