# How to merge two pandas DataFrames into single Multi-Index DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two DataFrames that are equally indexed, but each represents a different aspect of my full dataset.
For instance:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import date

df_price = pd.DataFrame(
    index=pd.date_range(start=date(2021, 1, 1), end=date(2021, 1, 3), freq="D"),
    columns=["A", "B", "C"],
    data={"A": [1, 2, 3], "B": [4, 5, 6], "C": [7, 8, 9]}
)
df_quantity = pd.DataFrame(
    index=pd.date_range(start=date(2021, 1, 1), end=date(2021, 1, 3), freq="D"),
    columns=["A", "B", "C"],
    data={"A": [9, 8, 7], "B": [6, 5, 4], "C": [3, 2, 1]}
)
```

What I want is the equivalent of doing this:

```
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([["A", "B", "C"], ["price", "quantity"]], names=["first", "second"])
df_total = pd.DataFrame(
    index=pd.date_range(start=date(2021, 1, 1), end=date(2021, 1, 3), freq="D"),
    columns=index,
    data=[[1, 9, 4, 6, 7, 3], [2, 8, 5, 5, 8, 2], [3, 7, 6, 4, 9, 1]]
)
```

```
first          A              B              C         
second     price quantity price quantity price quantity
2021-01-01     1        9     4        6     7        3
2021-01-02     2        8     5        5     8        2
2021-01-03     3        7     6        4     9        1
```

Any ideas? I have tried the common methods of join and merge, but all I could do is add the columns with suffixes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked over the `concatenate()` method and found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44263339/13574635). It led me to create a function to solve my problem. It can handle multiple `DataFrame` objects in once

```
from typing import Dict
import pandas as pd

def in_merge(dfs_dict: Dict[str, pd.DataFrame]) -> pd.DataFrame:
    return (
        pd.concat(
            dfs_dict,
            axis=1,
            names=["attribute", "item"],
        )
        .swaplevel(axis=1)
        .sort_index(axis=1)
    )
```

```
|                     |   ('A', 'price') |   ('A', 'quality') |   ('A', 'quantity') |   ('B', 'price') |   ('B', 'quality') |   ('B', 'quantity') |   ('C', 'price') |   ('C', 'quality') |   ('C', 'quantity') |
|:--------------------|-----------------:|-------------------:|--------------------:|-----------------:|-------------------:|--------------------:|-----------------:|-------------------:|--------------------:|
| 2021-01-01 00:00:00 |                1 |                  4 |                   9 |                4 |                  5 |                   6 |                7 |                  6 |                   3 |
| 2021-01-02 00:00:00 |                2 |                  4 |                   8 |                5 |                  5 |                   5 |                8 |                  6 |                   2 |
| 2021-01-03 00:00:00 |                3 |                  4 |                   7 |                6 |                  5 |                   4 |                9 |                  6 |                   1 |
```

Comment: You can pass the dictionary itself into `concat` and it will automatically fill out the `keys` argument for you. So you can simplify your `concat` call to `concat(df_dict, axis=1, names=["attribute", "item"])`

Answer (score 2):

One option:

(i) `join` the two DataFrames

(ii) split column names on `'_'` and because we want to use `from_tuples`, map the sublists to tuples

(iii) use `pd.MultiIndex` to convert the column to MultiIndex

(iv) sort column names to match the desired outcome

```
df_total = df_price.join(df_quantity, lsuffix='_price', rsuffix='_quantity')
df_total.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(map(tuple, df_total.columns.str.split('_')))
df_total = df_total.reindex(df_total.columns.sort_values(), axis=1)
```

Output:

```
               A              B              C         
           price quantity price quantity price quantity
2021-01-01     1        9     4        6     7        3
2021-01-02     2        8     5        5     8        2
2021-01-03     3        7     6        4     9        1
```

Comment: Great solution, very elegant. I think the last line should be replaced by this `df_total = df_total.sort_index(axis=1)`, so it doesn't mix the values. Thanks!

Comment: @pelelter you're right. I fixed it. but is the expected outcome in the question correct? the data for A on 2021-01-02 doesn't seem to match the data from the original dfs

Comment: It looks right to me. For me it looks the same as your last edit